# Different length of array when cv2.imread receives cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE as argument

Tags: python, machine-learning, opencv

```
Training_Data=[]
IMG_SIZE=100

def build():
    Directory="D:\projects\Machine_learning\Dog_Cat\PetImages"
    CATEGORY=["Cat","Dog"]
    for category in CATEGORY:
        path=os.path.join(Directory,category)
        class_num=CATEGORIES.index(category)
        for img in tqdm(os.listdir(path)):
            try:
                img_array=cv2.imread(
                    os.path.join(path,img),
                    cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE
                )
                new_array=cv2.resize(img_array(IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE))
                Training_Data.append([new_array,class_num])
            except Exception as e:
               pass
```

When I don't pass cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE, it gives different length of array:

```
img_array=cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img))
```

> X = 74598
>
> Y = 24886

Why it is appending 3 times more element in `training_data` when `cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` is not used?

Comment: I think it defaults to BGR, i.e. 3*8 bits per pixel. Grayscale is just 8 bits (1 byte) per pixel. Also, please have a look at [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, when you don't pass `cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` as argument, `cv2.imread` will read your image with three channels (it will load your image as RGB). When you pass `cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` as argument, your amount of bits per pixels is changing (you'll only need 1*8 bit per pixel instead of 3*8).

If you want, you can check out your image [depth and channels](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-depth) using `depth()` and `channels()` functions, it might help you to better understand what is happening.